# How to group and aggregate data based on multiple keys?

Tags: javascript

Given the following data:

```js
var data = [
  { material: 100, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 100, color: "Red", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
]
```

i must achieve a table-array with the following results:

```
// user | material | color | counter
// 424    100        Blue    1
// 424    100        Red     1
// 424    200        Blue    2
//  20    200        Blue    3
```

I've tried something like: (short code)

```js
const merged = data.reduce((r, { user, material, color, ...rest }) => {
  const key = `${user}-${material}-${color}`
  r[key] = r[key] || { user, material, color }
  r[key]["color"].push(rest)
  return r
}, {})
```

but could not achieve the solution.
Any help appreciated guys!

Comment: First of all, you are not even maintaining a `counter` and secondly, why are you pushing `rest` into `color` key which is definitely a string?

Comment: Hey there! thanks for your comments, i was trying to understand how ...rest works and was an example to show what i've tried so far. You are right about counter for not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just count the occurences and get an array of objects as result;

```js
var data = [{ material: 100, color: "Blue", user: 424 }, { material: 100, color: "Red", user: 424 }, { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 }, { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 }, { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 }, { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 }, { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 }],
    merged = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { user, material, color}) => {
    const key = `${user}-${material}-${color}`;
        r[key] = r[key] || { user, material, color, counter: 0 };
        r[key].counter++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina Scholz that did the trick! thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet could help you go on

```js
const data = [
  { material: 100, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 100, color: "Red", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 424 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
  { material: 200, color: "Blue", user: 20 },
]

const counter = {}

data.forEach(({ material, user, color }) => {
  counter[`${user}-${material}-${color}`] =
    (counter[`${user}-${material}-${color}`] || 0) + 1
})

console.log(counter)
```

Answer (score 1):

solution with [lodash v4.17.15](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15):

```
const result = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy(({material, color, user}) => `${material}-${color}-${user}`)
    .map((items) => [
        items[0].user,
        items[0].material,
        items[0].color,
        items.length,
    ])
    .value();
```

solution with native js:

```
function getHashObj({material, color, user}) {
    return `${material}-${color}-${user}`;
}

function getHashArr([user, material, color]) {
    return `${material}-${color}-${user}`;
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const existed = acc.find((a) => getHashArr(a) === getHashObj(item));

    if (!existed) {
        return [ ...acc, [
            item.user,
            item.material,
            item.color,
            1,
        ]];
    }

    existed[3] += 1;

    return acc;
}, []);
```